# Anaconda Navigator filled with random apps

Tags: anaconda

As you can see in attached I'm having issues with my Anaconda Navigator Home with random python libraries showing up as Applications. Additionally, it doesn't detected the already installed R.

[image: You can see my Current Anaconda Application Screen here]

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

These extra apps come from conda forge. 
Check the channels button at the top of the screen to see if conda forge is in your list of channels. If it is and you either don't need it or don't know what it is, you can remove it by clicking the delete icon. This will stop the extra applications showing.

Comment: Anaconda now installs applications that can't be removed, e.g. Datalore and IBM Watson, obviously because of commercial agreements.

Comment: I think there is a remove option that will work on watson etc.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFHA8_1.2.0/wmla_uninstall.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on one of my environments and when accessing the prompt for that environment, running [`conda clean`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/clean.html) solved the problem:

```
conda clean -a
```

Then

```
conda update --all
```

If after this RStudio is not installed in that environment (it is in my case), in the environment prompt, install [RStudio](https://anaconda.org/r/rstudio) with

`conda install -c r rstudio`